# Understanding roots of a particular function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

Let $a$ and $b$ strictly positive known vectors in $\mathbb{R}^N$ with $\sum_i a_i = 1$, let $\theta \in (0,1)$, and consider the function $$ g(x)\equiv\sum a_{i}\frac{1+x^{\theta}}{1+b_{i}x} - 1.$$ I am interested in understanding the strictly positive roots of this function. It is clear that $g(0) = 0$, $g'(0)>0$ and that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g(x) = -1$, so there is at least one strictly positive root. But could there be more?

If $N = 1$ then evaluating at $g(x) = 1$ we have $$ \frac{d\ln g(x)}{d\ln x}=\theta\frac{x^{\theta}}{1+x^{\theta}}-\frac{bx}{1+bx}=\frac{bx}{1+bx}\left(\theta-1\right)<0,$$ implying that there would be only one positive solution. I think this is the case with $N > 1$, but am not sure how to check this. The problem is that with $N > 1$ I can no longer directly sign $g'(x)$ by using $g(x)=1$. Any suggestions would be appreciated.